# How to do a simple table join in fluent Nhibernate 4

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to figure out how to join two tables (Node and NodeDetails) that have one foreign key relating them. Basically I'm looking for the nhibernate linq version of this sql query:

```
SELECT node.ObjectType, nodeDetails.Name, nodeDetails.SizeInFeet
FROM node
left join nodeDetails
on node.ID = nodedetails.nodeID
ORDER BY node.ObjectType;
```

Since I'm doing a join and I don't need all of the columns, I created another entity called NodeDetailsView that is suppose to hold the result. My C# code looks like this:

```
Node n = null;
NodeDetails nd = null;

var q = _session.QueryOver<NodeDetails>(() => nd)
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.NodeID, () => n)
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<NodeDetailsView>());

 IList<NodeDetailsView> r = t.List<NodeDetailsView>();
```

I end up with this exception:
{"Unknown column 'this_.SizeInFeet' in 'field list'"}
I dont think my linq query above is right and my mapping is probably not correct. Could you guys look over it and give me a few pointers? Thanks!

My entity classes:
Node.cs

```
public class Node
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string ObjectType { get; set; }
    public virtual string Location {get; set;}
}
```

Nodetail.cs

```
public class NodeDetails : IVersionedEntity
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Node NodeID { get; set; }
    public virtual int SizeInFeet { get; set; }
    public virtual float Price { get; set; }
}
```

The view class NodeDetailsView.cs

```
public class NodeDetailsView
{
    public virtual string ObjectType { get; set; }
    public virtual string SizeInFeet { get; set; }
    public virtual int TotalSpace { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent Mappings

```
public class NodeMap: ClassMap<Node>
{
    public WorldObjectMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.ObjectType).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Location).Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class NodDetailsMap : ClassMap<NodeDetails>
{
    public NodDetailsMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        References(x => x.NodeID).Column("ID");
        Map(x => x.MarketPrice).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.SizeInFeet).Nullable();
    }
}

public class NodeDetailsViewMapping : ClassMap<NodeDetailsView>
{
    public WorldObjectLeasesViewMapping()
    {
        Map(x => x.ObjectType).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Name).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.SizeInFeet);
    }
}
```

Comment: `QueryOver()` is _queryover_, an NHibernate specific API, and not LINQ. If you want to use LINQ, start with `session.Query<EntityType>()`.

Comment: Also note that FluentNHibernate is only an API to define the mappings, it is not involved later when doing querying. What you're really asking is "How to query X in NHibernate?". Cole's response below seems like a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I would use the Linq provider rather than QueryOver.  If you did it would look something like this:

```
using NHibernate.Linq

IList<NodeDetailsView> r = _session.Query<NodeDetails>()
                .Select(x => new NodeDetailsView
                       {
                           ObjectType = x.NodeID.ObjectType,
                           SizeInFeet = x.SizeInFeet,
                           TotalSpace = "not sure what this is..."
                       }
                .ToList()
```

There is no need to map `NodeDetailsView` as this appears to be a DTO/Model.  You only map objects that are either representative of a database table or view.

It also appears from the above that `SizeInFeet` differs from object to object.  One is a `string` and the other is an `int`.  If this is really the case you'll have to do a conversion there in the query with something like `SizeInFeet = x.SizeInFeet.ToString()`